# "From" field on PHP email not working

Tags: php, email

I had put a PHP email system up, and that's working fine. When I send a message it comes up as "a7269592@srv15.000webhost.com" How could I get it so when someones opens the email it's from my company name? Here's my PHP. Thanks in advance
-Ben

```
    <?php    

$headers=  "Inquiry: " . $_POST['inquiry'] . "\r\n" .
// ect etc
"Contact: " . $_POST['contact'];
"BCC: " . $_POST['email'];
$from = "someonelse@example.com";

$header1 = " ";
$header2 = " ";
$to_myself = "";
$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
$thank_you = " ".$common_data;
mail($to_myself, "Your Memory", $common_data, $header1);
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $thank_you, $header2); ?>
```

Comment: This program looks like it allows sending email with any content to any selected person. This is likely to be abused by spammers.

Comment: sarnold's point is understated. It would be more accurate to suggest that code like this in the wild is unlike to NOT to be abused by spammers...a lot.  Please do the world a favor and do not post this code to a public server.

Comment: I was going to put in  a capchta  verification code. I was just doing this one step at a time. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $headers  = "Contact: ".$_POST['contact']."\r\n";
 $headers .= "BCC: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: Your Company <your_company@example.com>\r\n";
 mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $thank_you, $headers);
```

You should also read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: how could I include the message into this email?

Comment: The Message? Isn't that the content of the `$thank_you` variable?

Comment: Well just do `mail($to_visitor,'Your Memory',$message,$headers);` then. And you should seriously try reading the documentation for the `mail()` function.

Comment: How could I change $to_vistor to The BCC

Comment: You could read the documentation=) or `$headers .= "BCC: ".$to_visitor."\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

I am using a class. It's much more easier. You can try this too. I took this class from somewhere and I improved it to match with my requirement.

```
<?php

class Mail 
{ 

   private $arrTo = array(); 
   private $arrCC = array(); 
   private $arrBCC = array(); 
   private $strContent = ""; 
   private $strSubject = ""; 
   private $arrHeader = array(); 
   private $arrAttachments = array(); 
   private $numPriority = 3; 
   private $strCharSet = "iso-8859-1"; 
   private $strContentType = "text/plain"; 
   private $strEncoding = "8bit"; 

   /*
    * Mail::addUser()
    * 
    * Adds a user to send the email to
    *
    * @param String $strAddress : Holds an email address
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return Integer
    */
   public function addUser($strAddress){ 
      if($this->emailCheck($strAddress)){             
         $this->arrTo[] = $strAddress; 
         return 1; 
      }else{ 
         return 0; 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::removeUser()
    * 
    *  Removes an address from the array
    *
    * @param String $strAddress : Holds an email address 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function removeUser($strAddress){ 
      //create array or arrays to check 
      $arrVars = array('arrTo', 'arrCC', 'arrBCC'); 
      foreach($arrVars as $resVars){ 
         //sees if the item exists in the array 
         $numKey = array_search($strAddress, $this->{$resVars}); 
         if(isset($numKey)){ 
            //remove the email address 
            $this->{$resVars}[$numKey] = "";                         
         } 
         unset($numKey); 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addCC()
    * 
    * Adds a CC user to send to
    *
    * @param String $strAddress : Holds an email address
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return Integer
    */     
   public function addCC($strAddress){ 
      if($this->emailCheck($strAddress)){    
         $this->arrCC[] = $strAddress; 
         return 1; 
      }else{ 
         return 0; 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addBCC()
    * 
    * Adds a BCC user to send to
    *
    * @param String $strAddress : Holds an email address 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return Integer
    */ 
   public function addBCC($strAddress){ 
      if($this->emailCheck($strAddress)){ 
         $this->arrBCC[] = $strAddress; 
         return 1; 
      }else{ 
         return 0; 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addReplyTo()
    * 
    * Adds a reply-to email address
    *
    * @param String $strEmail : Holds the reply-to email address 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */    
   public function addReplyTo($strEmail){ 
      if($this->emailCheck($strEmail)){ 
         $this->addHeader("Reply-to: $strEmail"); 
      } 
   } 


   /*
    * Mail::setContent()
    * 
    * Adds the content of the email
    *
    * @param String $strText : Holds the email content 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */   
   public function setContent($strText){ 
      $this->strContent = $strText; 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::setSubject()
    * 
    * Adds the email subject 
    *
    * @param String $strText : Holds the email subject 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */       
   public function setSubject($strText){ 
      $this->strSubject = $strText; 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::setFrom()
    * 
    * Adds the sender info to the headers 
    *
    * @param String $strText : Holds the details of who the email is from 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */  
   public function setFrom($strText){ 
      $this->addHeader("From: $strText"); 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::setHTML()
    * 
    * Sets the email to allow html
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */      
   public function setHTML(){    
      $this->strContentType = "text/html";    
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::setPlain()
    * 
    * Sets the email to plain text 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */    
   public function setPlain(){    
      $this->strContentType = "text/plain";       
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::setPriority()
    * 
    * Sets the email priority from 1 – Urgent to 5 – not so 
    *
    * @param Integer $numPriority : The email priority 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function setPriority($numPriority){ 
      $this->numPriority = $numPriority; 
   }    

   /*
    * Mail::addReadConfirmationEmail()
    * 
    * Ensures that a confirmation email is sent when read 
    *
    * @param String $strEmail : Email address to send read confirmation to 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function addReadConfirmationEmail($strEmail){ 
      if($this->emailCheck($strEmail)){ 
         $this->addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: <$strEmail>"); 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addHeader()
    * 
    * Adds the header details
    *
    * @param String $strText : Holds the header details 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */  
   public function addHeader($strText){ 
      $this->arrHeader[] = $strText; 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addAttachment()
    * 
    * Adds an attachment to be sent with the email
    *
    * @param String $strFile : The file that you want to attach
    * @param String $strName : The name of the attachment you want displayed
    * @param String $strType : The MIME type of the file
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */   
   public function addAttachment($strFile, $strName, $strType){ 
      //check to make sure the file exists 
      if(file_exists($strFile)){ 
         $this->arrAttachments[] = array('path' => $strFile, 'name' => $strName, 'type' => $strType); 
      } 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::send()
    * 
    * Sends the email to all the required people 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function send(){ 
      //get all the emails in a string to use 
      $strTo = implode(", ", $this->arrTo); 

      //add any CC addresses if needed 
      if($this->arrCC){ 
         $this->addHeader("Cc: ".implode(", ", $this->arrCC)); 
      } 

      //add any BCC addresses if needed 
      if($this->arrBCC){ 
         $this->addHeader("Bcc: ".implode(", ", $this->arrBCC)); 
      } 

      //append any attachments to the end of the content 
      if(count($this->arrAttachments)){ 
         $this->appendAttachments(); 
      } 

      //add the additional headers 
      $this->addAdditionalHeaders(); 

      //implode the headers as they need to be in a single string 
      $strHeader = implode("\r\n", $this->arrHeader); 

      // Set this if you have your own domain
      //ini_set('sendmail_from', 'yourdomain.com');

      //send the email 
      mail($strTo, $this->strSubject, $this->strContent, $strHeader); 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::appendAttachments()
    * 
    * Appends any attachments to the end of the email content
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */
   public function appendAttachments(){ 
      //create a unique boundary value 
      $strBoundary = "H2O-".time(); 

      //add the boundary to the headers 
      $this->addHeader("Content-Type: multipart/alternitive; boundary=$strBoundary"); 

      //if there is content to the email already we need to add the boundary and content type 
      if($this->strContent){ 
         $strContent = "–$strBoundary\r\n"; 
         $strContent .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: {$this->strEncoding}\r\n"; 
         $strContent .= "Content-type: {$this->strContentType}; charset={$this->strCharSet}\r\n\r\n"; 

         $this->strContent = $strContent.$this->strContent."\r\n\r\n\r\n"; 
      } 

      //loop through all the attachments 
      foreach($this->arrAttachments as $arrFile){ 
         //read the content of the file into a string and base64 encode and split into the correct chunk size 
         $strData = chunk_split(base64_encode(implode("", file($arrFile['path'])))); 

         //add the attachments       
         $strAttachment = "–$strBoundary\r\n"; 
         $strAttachment .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
         $strAttachment .= "Content-Type: {$arrFile['type']}; name={$arrFile['name']}\r\n"; 
         $strAttachment .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$arrFile['name']}\r\n\r\n"; 
         $strAttachment .= "$strData\r\n"; 

         //add the attachment to the email content 
         $this->strContent .= $strAttachment; 

         unset($strAttachment); 
      } 

      //add the closing boundary    
      $this->strContent .= "–$strBoundary–"; 
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::addAdditionalHeaders()
    * 
    * Adds additional headers for content type and priority etc 
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return void
    */   
   public function addAdditionalHeaders(){ 
      $this->addHeader("MIME-Version: 1.0"); 

      //add the content type and charset if there are no attachments 
      if(!count($this->arrAttachments)){ 
         $this->addHeader("Content-type: {$this->strContentType}; charset={$this->strCharSet}");       
      } 

      //add the priority 
      $this->addHeader("X-Priority: $this->numPriority");    
   } 

   /*
    * Mail::emailCheck()
    * 
    * Checks to ensure that the email address is valid 
    *
    * @param String $strAddress : Holds an email address
    *
    * @access public
    * 
    * @return Integer
    */      
   public function emailCheck($strAddress){ 
      if(ereg("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", $strAddress)){ 
         return 1; 
      }else{ 
         return 0; 
      } 
   } 
} 
?>
```

Implementation:

```
$email = new Mail();
$email->addUser($toAddress);
$email->setFrom("Your Company Name<" . $yourCompanyEMail. ">");
$email->setHTML();
$email->setSubject("Subject goes here");
$email->setContent("Mail body goes here");
$email->send();
```

Cheers !

Comment: This class and implementation would still be open to header injection attacks and other basic SPAM problems (like the code above).  This will make sending the messages easier, but does not sanitize inputs (except email address, with an incomplete RegEx that will block valid addresses). For a non-expert user a class like this could lead the programmer to feel safe while opening themselves to being a SPAM provider.

Comment: @ acrosman. Thanks for your comment. I will try to improve this further.